# Git tarda demasiado en subir cambios

Tags: git, github, git-push

Buenas noches, alguien sabe porque al tratar de subir cambios en Git se tarda demasiado. Cuando digo demasiado les hablo que desde el Jueves pasado trato de subir cambios y hasta hoy no puedo subir nada. He tratado de subir cambios mediante el VS CODE y no lo he conseguido, cuando lo hago a través de comandos es exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: No es que tarde en realidad no puedes subir nada, revisa tus credenciales o permisos si estan dentro de un proxy.

Comment: Buena acotación @Jorgesys jajaja. Has intentado con otro repositorio? Clonaste por https?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo leer, en primera instancia tienes que ver si lo estás haciendo por https, ver tus credenciales y los permisos en el proxy.

Para ver dónde está el problema, se tiene que analizar en qué proceso empieza a generarse el inconveniente. Dependiendo de esto por descartes vas solucionando lo que interfiere en tu trabajo.

Como te comentan lo mejor es usar GIT para subir los ficheros al servidor, el problema es que no todos los servidores llevan GIT instalado.

Puedes probar `git-ftp` y ver si es lo que necesitas: http://git-ftp.github.io/git-ftp/ No lo he usado nunca, así que no te puedo decir si va bien o no. Te dejo un pequeño tutorial en castellano: http://blog.phenobarbital.info/2013/05/git-subiendo-archivos-usando-git-ftp/

Otra opción es usar herramientas como http://www.deployhq.com el inconveniente es que son de pago

Pero como no quiero que se quede sin una respuesta e intentar ayudar, puede leer este [tutorial de cambios en el repositorio](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Guardando-cambios-en-el-repositorio)

Comment: no creo que el problema sea que el servidor no tenga instalado __Git__ ya que por lo que leo solo quiere hacer un _push_ a su repositorio. Pero igual todo es posible ya que la pregunta tampoco especifica muy bien lo que quiere hacer y los errores que tiene, Buen aporte :)